# How to display only first row of count value others displayed as null in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

recently I wanted to retrieve only the first row of the count value others are displayed as null in PostgreSQL, but unfortunately, I can't get it.

```
with firstFunc as(
select count(function_name), function_name,function_id from pivot_da_middleware.get_de_kpis_full() group by function_name,function_id
),
secondFunc as(
select fl.function_name, gdkf.subgroup_name,gdkf.subgroup_id,fl.function_id from firstFunc fl
inner join pivot_da_middleware.get_de_kpis_full() gdkf 
on fl.function_id = gdkf.function_id
--where fl.function_name = 'Operations'
order by fl.function_name
),
thirdFunc as(
    -- second 
    select count(secondFunc.subgroup_name), secondFunc.subgroup_name,secondFunc.subgroup_id,function_id from secondFunc 
    group by secondFunc.subgroup_name,secondFunc.subgroup_id,secondFunc.function_id order by secondFunc.function_id
),
fourthFunc as(
select count(function_id),function_id from thirdFunc tf group by function_id
)

select * from fourthFunc ff right join thirdFunc tf2 on ff.function_id = tf2.function_id
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Expected Result:
[image]

Comment: @Phil i'm so sorry okay, mistake

Comment: If you want to see values only in the first row but not in other rows, I would suggest having two separate queries, let's say Q1 and Q2. Here make sure Q1 would fetch only one row i.e. first row and Q2 results in the rest of the rows. Then you can use UNION ALL to combine the result set and thus you are assured the intended row would always come in the beginning. Make sure you have mutually exclusive conditions in both Q1 and Q2 to avoid duplicates. Hope this would help.